# segueを使用した画面遷移が遷移するたびに重くなります。

Tags: swift, spritekit

segueとunwind segueを使用して画面遷移を行っているのですが、何回も遷移しているうちに処理が重くなっていき、まともに動作しなくなります。　なにか対策、改善策はありますか？

トップ画面➡︎(segue)メニュー画面➡︎(segue)ゲーム画面(spritekit)➡︎(segue)結果画面
➡︎(unwind segue) メニュー画面　という遷移の仕方を考えています。

Answer (score 1):

画面遷移で重くなるのでは無く、画面遷移で解放されるはずのインスタンスが残っていて、結果的に重くなっているのでは無いでしょうか？

プログラムにインスタンスが解放されているかどうかを確認する処理を組み込むとか、Instrumentsでメモリリークを調べるなどしてみるのが良いかと思いますよ。